# Multiple table CTE with numbering

Tags: sql-server, database, common-table-expression, data-manipulation, multiple-tables

I am struggling with Common Table Expression (CTE) for the database I have.

**tblDistricts**
DistrictID (pk)
District

**tblVillage**
VillageID (pk)
DistrictID
Village

**tblWard**
WardID (pk)
VillageID
DistrictID
Village

Below is how to create the sample database:

```
Create Table tblDistricts(
    [DistrictID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key Clustered,
    [District] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL
)


GO
Create Table tblVillage(
    [VillageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key Clustered,
    [DistrictID] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [Village] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL
)

GO
Create Table tblWards(
    [WardID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key Clustered,
    [DistrictID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VillageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Ward] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL
)

GO

Insert into tblDistricts Values ('Barolong')
Insert into tblDistricts Values ('Central_Bobonong')
Insert into tblDistricts Values ('Central_Boteti')
Insert into tblDistricts Values ('Central_Mahalapye')
Insert into tblDistricts Values ('Central_Tutume')
Insert into tblDistricts Values ('Chobe')
GO

Insert into tblVillage Values (1,'Bethel')
Insert into tblVillage Values (1,'Borobadilepe')
Insert into tblVillage Values (1,'Digawana')
Insert into tblVillage Values (1,'Dikhukhung')
Insert into tblVillage Values (1,'Dinatshana')

GO

Insert into tblVillage Values (2,'Bobonong')
Insert into tblVillage Values (2,'Damochojena')
Insert into tblVillage Values (2,'Kobojango')
GO

Insert into tblVillage Values (5,'Shakwe')
Insert into tblVillage Values (5,'Shoshong')
Insert into tblVillage Values (5,'Taupye')
Insert into tblVillage Values (5,'Tewane')
GO


Insert into tblWards Values (1,3,'Shakwe')
Insert into tblWards Values (1,3,'Shoshong')
Insert into tblWards Values (2,6,'Taupye')
Insert into tblWards Values (2,8,'Tewane')
Insert into tblWards Values (5,9,'Shakwe')

GO
```

I would like to have an output that looks like this and not sure if CTE's are the only option:

```
| ID| ParéntID | Item       | DistrictID | VillageID | WardID |

| 1 | 0        | District 1 |1           |0           |0      |
| 2 | 1        | Village  1 |1           |1           |0      |
| 3 | 1        | Village  2 |1           |2           |0      |
| 4 | 2        | Ward 1     |1           |1           |1      |
| 5 | 0        | District 2 |2           |0           |0      |
| 6 | 5        | Village 3  |2           |3           |0      |
| 7 | 6        | Ward     2 |2           |3           |2      |
```

I hope that I have provided sufficient information to my problem.

KK

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: What is Item column representing..

Comment: Start by adding the appropriate foreign keys so invalid values cannot exist. And can a Ward be associated to a district that is different from that of the associated village? Your schema allows that but I doubt that is intended.

Comment: @stickybit I had tried all the help I met on the net but none did the trick for me. However, I have resolved the issue. This is important as some third party products require this format for treeview binding for existing data which may not be readily in the required format. My issue, as opposed to the online help, was how to do this for n tables and not just two tables as normally shown on the net. Thank you for commenting on my post.

Comment: @JGFMK. The item column was to show the name of either the district, village or ward. I am using the output to show a tree structure of the three tables on a TreeView control.

Comment: @SMor. You are absolutely right, however I require all the hierarchy information when I do a selection on a treeview node control. Thank you.

Comment: If you've resolved your issue, you have the possibility to answer your own question with your solution (and earn the chocolate medals of self learner by the way ^^). This way, many other contributors may give you feedback and insights on it.